# NSTableview initializing problem with NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate

Tags: swift, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nstableview

I'm developing a MacOS application which displays data in a table where the data source is controlled by FetchedResultsController.
The problem is when initializing the application the `numberOfRows` method sometimes called before the `loadView` method.

Since the fetchedResultsController.performFetch method supposedly should be executed in loadView, when `numberOfRows` is executed before `loadView`, then `numberOfRows` returns 0 and an empty table is being shown.

What is strange the call order seems random, roughly half of the times the execution order is right, and in the other cases wrong.
Here is my code:

```
<!-- language: lang-swift -->
//MARK: Controller
class MetricsViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: NSTableView!

    let managedObjectContext = (NSApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Metrics> = {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Metrics>(entityName: "Metrics")
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [
            NSSortDescriptor(key: "ticker", ascending: true),
            NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false),
        ]
        let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

        // Configure Fetched Results Controller
        fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

        return fetchedResultsController
    }()

    //MARK: ViewController
    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        print("loadView")
        do {
            try self.fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
        } catch {
            let fetchError = error as NSError
            print("\(fetchError), \(fetchError.userInfo)")
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.tableColumns[0].sortDescriptorPrototype = fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.sortDescriptors![0]
        tableView.tableColumns[1].sortDescriptorPrototype = fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.sortDescriptors![1]
    }

    //MARK: TableViewDataSource
    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        print("numberofRows")
        return fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects?.count ?? 0
    }
```

Comment: *Since the fetchedResultsController.performFetch method supposedly should be executed in `loadView`,*. Where did you get this from?

Comment: Don't really remember, from some tutorial I found.